# Using vm_read to read another process memory

Tags: c, kernel, low-level, mach

I have written some code in order to read another process memory. This is for macOS/GNU Mach.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <mach/mach.h>
#include <mach/mach_vm.h>

int main() {
    pid_t pid;
    printf("PID: ");
    scanf("%d", &pid);
    vm_address_t address;
    printf("Address: ");
    scanf("%lx", &address);
    vm_offset_t readMem;
    vm_map_read_t task = task_for_pid(mach_task_self(), pid, &task);
    mach_msg_type_number_t size = sizeof(int);
    kern_return_t result = vm_read(task, address, (pointer_t)sizeof(int), &readMem, &size);
    if (result) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cant read, result 0x%x\n", result);
    }
    printf("%lu", readMem); 
}
```

Upon running it and providing a valid PID, it returns MACH_SEND_INVALID_DEST.

Comment: I think your real issue is that `task_for_pid` does _not_ return a `vm_map_read_t`. It returns `kern_return_t`. So, the `&task` would set it correctly but the return value blows that away. You want: `kern_return_t result = task_for_pid(mach_task_self(), pid, &task);` and check the return value as you do for `vm_read` From a web search, other examples use `task_t task;` or `mach_port_t task;`

Comment: @CraigEstey That's weird... now the return value is `0x5` lol

Comment: There's scant documentation for `task_for_pid`. The web search produced only _three_ non-dup results. I presume you're using macOS (vs. "real" mach or XNU). I don't have access to one. So, I'm just searching, reading, and guessing. One page says "who needs it" when referring to `task_for_pid`. That aside, you also have to ensure that the `pid` you enter is owned by the same `uid` as your program is running under (or use `sudo`). And, that `address` maps to something in the target process/thread's address space.

Comment: sorry, the result is 0x5, the return value is gibberish. the actual value in memory is 12.

Comment: @CraigEstey Using `sudo` returned no error, but I am still getting gibberish.

Comment: The closest I found is: [Read/Write memory on OS X 10.8.2 with vm_read and vm_write](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12759378/5382650) but it's 10 years old ...

Comment: Since [IIRC] Apple closed macOS source a few years back, the only way to examine the source might be to find a repo for the mach kernel or XNU kernel. Spotty, at best ... There ought to be a macOS specific API that supports this functionality, just not the [underlying] mach API.

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is late, but it might be useful to others who encounter the same problem.

**Problems**

1. As Craig Estey pointed out, `task_for_pid()` returns `kern_return_t`.
2. You are not checking for potential errors.
3. The way you are reading the data after obtaining the pointer is incorrect.
4. Run the program with sudo.

I modified your code to make it more clear, added some error checking and made proper reading. By the comments you made, I believe you are trying to read an integer, so I adapted the code to fit that need.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <mach/mach.h>
#include <mach/mach_vm.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void check_result(kern_return_t kern_res, char * msg)
{
    if (kern_res != KERN_SUCCESS) {
            if (msg == NULL)
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mach_error_string(kern_res));
            else
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s : %s\n", msg, mach_error_string(kern_res));
            exit(1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    printf("PID: ");
    scanf("%d", &pid);

    vm_address_t address;
    printf("Address: ");
    scanf("%lx", &address);

    kern_return_t res;
    mach_port_t   task_self = mach_task_self();
    mach_port_t   other_task;

    res = task_for_pid(task_self, pid, &other_task);
    check_result(res, "Error getting task");

    void * data;
    mach_msg_type_number_t size = sizeof(int);
    vm_size_t size_to_read = (vm_size_t) sizeof(int);

    res = vm_read(other_task, address, size_to_read, (vm_offset_t *) &data, &size);
    check_result(res, "Error reading virtual memory");

    char * char_ptr = (char *) data;
    fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", (int) char_ptr[0]);
}
```

I tested it and I made sure it works as intended. Please let me know of any improvement!